# Dot net nuke search page not working

Tags: dotnetnuke

My dot net nuke website's search page showing 404 error.
For example when i enter a search string and press enter key. it will navigate to

localhost:40188/SearchResults/tabid/86/Default.aspx&Search=efeeeeffe

with 404 error.

This error is causing because of that '&' in the url. How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: It's not a valid URL. How do you end up with it in the first place? Filling out a search form should not have this result

Comment: i have just added the search module

Comment: Who creates this URL, can you elaborate? How does it come about?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that **ALL** files have read and write access on the server... I had the same problem and found a handful of files that did not have read and write access...

Answer (score 0):

What version of DNN are you using? Search was changed from ground-up starting 7.1